# Change parameters of doPost()

Tags: java, servlets

I have a basic login page, that accepts the username and password, and redirects to a login servlet to authenticate the details.

I also have a filter that captures any requests coming to the login servlet, creates a new object that has the incoming request object as one of its parameters and passes it on.

I have changed the parameters in the doPost() method to reflect the new objects it should receive. I have also reflected the changes in the service method.

However, I'm still getting an error that
HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL.

Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You've changed the signature of `doPost(...)`, so your method doesn't override the defaut `doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)` and is not called any more. In its place the default method is the one being called. The default `doPost` is the one that throws the 405 error.

Instead of changing the signature of your doPost, include your object in the attributes of the request in the filter (`request.setAttribute("nameOfMyAttribute", myObject)`), and retrieve it inside your doPost in the servlet using `request.getAttribute("nameOfMyAttribute")`

Important thing: don't confuse parameters with attributes.

Comment: the problem is that i'm looking for a work around, in case cookies are disabled by the browser. I'm changing the signature of doPost() in order to pass a custom Request object which has the incoming request object, as well as the current session object. When i try adding my session object as an attribute as you suggested, my other jsp pages can't get that value.

Comment: P.S. URL Re-writing is not a feasible solution because of the security issues.